# How to combine multiple rows into a column based on a condition in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as follows.

```
Category table
+------------+------------+--------------+
| CategoryID | Name       | CategoryCode |
+------------+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Fixed      |              |
|          2 | Consumable |              |
|          3 | Intangible |              |
+------------+------------+--------------+

Type table
+--------+------------+-------------------------+----------+
| TypeID | CategoryID | Name                    | TypeCode |
+--------+------------+-------------------------+----------+
|      1 |          1 | Furniture               |          |
|      2 |          1 | Computers & Peripherals |          |
|      3 |          2 | Keyboards               |          |
|      4 |          2 | Other                   |          |
|      5 |          3 | Software                |          |
+--------+------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

The result I want is like this

```
+------------+------------+------------------------------------+
| CategoryID | Category   | Types                              |
+------------+------------+------------------------------------+
|          1 | Fixed      | Furniture, Computers & Peripherals |
|          2 | Consumable | Keyboards, other                   |
|          3 | Intangible | Software                           |
+------------+------------+------------------------------------+
```

Appriciate if you could help me with wirting the query in MySQL

Comment: Read up on the basics of JOINS, if you are unfamiliar - and then go check out [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution

```
SELECT
    a.CategoryId,
    a.`Name` Category,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.`Name`) Types
FROM
    Category a
INNER JOIN Type b ON b.CategoryID = a.CategoryId 
GROUP BY a.CategoryId
```

Comment: I'd also put a.`Name` in the GROUP BY, to ensure MySQL forward compatibility.

Comment: @Plantour this will not work with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` in order to work. You need all the columns in the select part of the group by or to be an aggregation function like `MAX`, `SUM`

Comment: @Plantour that is what @jarlh meant on the comment, your group by should be : `group by a.CategoryId ,a.Name;` Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/89